# Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "deviceName" which is an invalid capability.. Getting errors

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, automation, appium

I have changed from desired capabilities to UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();

STILL GETTING ERROR

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setup
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/AcceptedW3CCapabilityKeys
at io.appium.java_client.remote.options.BaseOptions.(BaseOptions.java:54)
at test.java.launch.setup(launch.java:30)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/BaseAndroidTest.java)

Use `UiAutomator2Options` instead of `DesiredCapabilities`

Comment: UiAutomator2Options cp = new UiAutomator2Options();
  

  cp.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
  cp.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Prarthana");
  cp.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
  cp.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "10");
  // cp.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "11");
  cp.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 60);
  cp.setCapability("autoLaunch", true);    I have used as you can see above still my script is not runing